# How to get text section symbol in front of section and subsection?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I wanna to get the text symbol `§` in front of section and subsection in my thesis and in table of contents, but I don't have any idea. Any of your help be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried this `\S`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inserting \S in front of section or chapter headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340449/inserting-s-in-front-of-section-or-chapter-headings)