# Theorem numbering problem

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I have a document and the sections are given as

```
\section*{\S 1. Introduction}

\section*{\S 2. Main Results}
```

How can I number theorems, definitions, propositions as Theorem 2.1, Definition 3.2, etc. with this section numbering?

Comment: Why are you using `\section*` and numbering your sections by hand? Why not just use `\section`? If your issue is that you want the `\S` symbol to show up, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340449/inserting-s-in-front-of-section-or-chapter-headings

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution borrows from [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340471/5001) to the query [Inserting \S in front of section or chapter headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/340449/5001).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Automatically prefix "\S" to numbers in section-level headers:
\makeatletter
%% See pp. 26f. of 'The LaTeX Companion,' 2nd. ed.
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
    {\csname the#1\endcsname\space}%      default
    {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}%   individual control
\newcommand{\section@cntformat}{\S\thesection.\space}
%\newcommand{\subsection@cntformat}{\S\thesubsection.\space}
%\newcommand{\subsubsection@cntformat}{\S\thesubsubsection.\space}
%\newcommand{\paragraph@cntformat}{\S\theparagraph.\space}
%\newcommand{\subparagraph@cntformat}{\S\thesubparagraph.\space}
\makeatletter

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\dots

\section{Main Results}
\begin{thm} Hello \dots \end{thm}

\section{Additional Results}
\stepcounter{defn} % just for this example
\begin{defn} World \dots \end{defn}
    
\end{document}
```